# nmake : NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/nologo"'

Tags: makefile, nmake

I have just downloaded Net-SNMP code and trying  to build for Win OS. I have added my VC binaries in system path. The installation script is throwing error when executing below command:

```
system("nmake /nologo clean" . ($logging ? " > clean.out 2>&1" : "")) == 0 || die ($logging ? "Build error (see clean.out)" : "Build error (see above)");
```

The error is:

```
$ cat clean.out
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26730.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/nologo"'
Stop.
```

How can I resolve the issue?

```
MINGW64 /c/tools/netsnmp/net-snmp-5.8/win32
$ ./build.bat


Net-SNMP build and install options
==================================

1.  OpenSSL support:                disabled
2.  OpenSSL include directory:      C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include
3.  OpenSSL library director:       C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC
4.  Platform SDK support:           disabled

5.  Install path:                   c:/usr
6.  Install after build:            enabled

7.  Perl modules:                   disabled
8.  Install perl modules:           disabled

9.  Quiet build (logged):           enabled
10. Debug mode:                     disabled

11. IPv6 transports (requires SDK): disabled
12. winExtDLL agent (requires SDK): disabled

13. Link type:                      static

14. Install development files       disabled

F.  Finished - start build
Q.  Quit - abort build

Select option to set / toggle: F

Building...

Creating *.out log files.

Deleting old log files...
Running Configure...
Cleaning...
Build error (see clean.out) at build.pl line 196, <> line 1.

MINGW64 /c/tools/netsnmp/net-snmp-5.8/win32
$ cat clean.out

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26730.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/nologo"'
Stop.

MINGW64 /c/tools/netsnmp/net-snmp-5.8/win32
$ nmake /nologo clean

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26730.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/nologo"'
Stop.
```

Comment: `cat`? Is there cygwin involved? Or mingw32?

Comment: I am using a mingw32 terminal to just execute the command

Comment: What happens if you don't use mingw32?

Comment: I tried and I get a error - 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  I am trying to add perl module in system PATH but not sure of /usr/bin/perl.exe windows path

Comment: Installing Perl for Windows resolve the issue when I ran the script from cmd

Answer (score 0):

I successfully built NetSNMP from the Visual Studio x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 by editing the build.pl python file and replacing all instances of "nmake /nologo" with "nmake"